# Get a view to all T's in std::vector<std::tuple<Ts...>>

Tags: c++, vector, tuples, c++14, c++17

Imagine I have a container which is similar to `std::vector<std::tuple<Ts...>>`.

From that, I would like to get a "`view`" (non-copying) to all `T`'s such that I can operate on that view as if it would be a *standard-like* container.

So what I would like to have:

```
using tuple_vector = std::vector<std::tuple<int,float,double>>;
tuple_vector tuple_vec = {{1, 4.f, 8.},
                          {2, 5.f, 9.},
                          {3, 6.f, 10.},
                          {4, 7.f, 11.}}

auto int_view = view<int>(tuple_vec);
^^^
type should be some kind of non-owning reference 

// what I would like to do
int_view[0] = 10; // modify
assert(int_view[0] == std::get<int>(tuple_vec[0])); // modification should modify tuple_vec as well
```

I have tried `std::transform`, but then I am getting a *owning copy* of all `int`'s.

```
std::vector<int> int_vec(tuple_vec.size());
std::transform(tuple_vec.begin(), tuple_vec.end(), int_vec.begin(), [&](const auto& elem) {
    return std::get<int>(elem);
});
```

I am not sure if this is possible at all, but if so, I would appreciate any hints or directions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a vector of [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper):

```
template <typename T, typename ContainerOfTuples>
auto make_refs_to(ContainerOfTuples& tuples) {
    using RefType = std::reference_wrapper<T>;

    std::vector<RefType> refs;
    refs.reserve(std::size(tuples));
    std::transform(std::begin(tuples), std::end(tuples), std::back_inserter(refs),
                   [](auto& tup) -> RefType { return {std::get<T>(tup)}; });
    return refs;
}

auto double_view = make_refs_to<double>(tuple_vec);
double_view[1].get() += 3.14;  // Caveat: must access through .get().
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e86b1597311cd5a)

---

Going further... here's how we can get references to many types:

```
namespace detail {

// When many types are asked for, return a tuple of references.
template <typename... T> struct RefTypeImpl {
    using type = std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<T>...>;
};

// When a single type is asked for, return a single reference.
template <typename T> struct RefTypeImpl<T> {
    using type = std::reference_wrapper<T>;
};

// When two types are asked for, return a pair for more convenient access.
template <typename T, typename U> struct RefTypeImpl<T, U> {
    using type = std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<T>, std::reference_wrapper<U>>;
};

}  // namespace detail

template <typename... Ts, typename ContainerOfTuples>
auto make_refs_to(ContainerOfTuples& tuples) {
    using RefType = typename detail::RefTypeImpl<Ts...>::type;

    std::vector<RefType> refs;
    refs.reserve(std::size(tuples));
    std::transform(std::begin(tuples), std::end(tuples), std::back_inserter(refs),
                   [](auto& tup) -> RefType { return {std::get<Ts>(tup)...}; });
    return refs;
}

auto int_float_view = make_refs_to<int, float>(tuple_vec);
std::cout << (int_float_view[2].first.get() == 3) << '\n';
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/350e00fbc9f3c47a)

Comment: I like the idea with `std::reference_wrapper`! However, as you already pointed out, using `.get()` in order to retrieve the data is not ideal. I am not accepting the answer yet, maybe someone comes up with a better idea :)

Comment: @kanstar yup I can understand that. Personally I feel like needing to use `.get()` is a good thing since it serves as a reminder that it's a "view", not an actual object.

Comment: How would you deal with the situation where I would like to get a view to multiple `T's`, like `auto int_float_view = make_refs_to<int,float>(tuple_vec)`?

Comment: @kanstar I suppose the vector could hold a tuple of references in that case (added the code to the answer). However, going through so much complication makes me think you should actually be using a completely different strategy for organizing your data.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you using [Eric Niebler's ranges-v3 library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) (which is in the process of getting adopted into the standard - there's now a [Ranges TS](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges)), you can apply your intuition to use something like `std::transform`, but with a view:

```
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>

// ... etc. ...

auto int_view = tuple_vector | ranges::view::transform(
    [](auto& t)->auto&{ return std::get<int>(t);} );
```

See this in [action](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65970376758c8ce7)(Coliru), with modification of one of the elements even.

Note: This view becomes un-modifiable if we remove the `-> decltype(auto)`; the change is due to @deduplicator's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55787350/1593077).

Comment: Isn't `int_view` in this case a *const view*? What if I need a *modifiable* view?

Comment: @kanstar: Well - this will be modifiable,!

Comment: Thanks! That looks great!