# Is there a modifiable-view version of ranges::view::transform?

Tags: c++, range-v3

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <array>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>

int main() {
    using container = std::array<std::tuple<int,float,double>, 4>;
    container tuples {{
        {1, 4.f, 8.},
        {2, 5.f, 9.},
        {3, 6.f, 10.},
        {4, 7.f, 11.}
    }};

    auto int_view =
        tuples | ranges::view::transform( [](auto& t){return std::get<int>(t);} );

    // int_view[1] = 3; // (*)

    auto x = std::accumulate(int_view.begin(), int_view.end(), 0);
    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
}
```

This compiles and prints `10`; but - if I uncomment the `(*)` line - it doesn't compile, with GCC complaining about the left side of the equality not being an lvalue. I was kind of disappointed by that - I was sort of hoping the transformation would produce `int&`'s which I could assign to...

Is there something I can to make this a modifiable view? Or some other mechanism in the ranges library which would allow me the equivalent of a modifiable view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is very simple, if you think about it:

The transformation-function is actually a projection-function, and yours doesn't produce the references necessary for allowing modification of the source, because [the standard return type deduction rule for lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) uses the [rules for plain `auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto), and those never deduce references.

1. [One fix is changing to the deduction rules for `decltype(auto)`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65970376758c8ce7), which preserve references, and are thus better avoided unless you *know* they are right.

   ```
   auto int_view = tuples | ranges::view::transform(
       [](auto& t)->decltype(auto){return std::get<int>(t);});
   ```
2. Or you can explicitly ask for references with `auto&` or something more specific.

   ```
   auto int_view = tuples | ranges::view::transform(
       [](auto& t)->auto&{return std::get<int>(t);});
   ```
3. And finally nobody stops you from returning a proxy like `std::reference_wrapper`. Though that's a needless complication.

   ```
   auto int_view = tuples | ranges::view::transform(
       [](auto& t){return std::ref(std::get<int>(t));});
   ```